# file ended while scanning use of \sf@@@subfloat

Tags: errors, subfloats, includegraphics

i am trying add 3 figures like this:
[image]
My code looks like this (I got it from another post, see: [How to put 3 figures in Latex with 2 figures side by side and 1 below these side by side images but in middle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461417/how-to-put-3-figures-in-latex-with-2-figures-side-by-side-and-1-below-these-side))

```
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
    \subfloat[legend]{\label{a}\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{abb/plots/gauss_trigsize_20um.png}\hfill
    \subfloat[legend]{\label{b}\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{abb/plots/gauss_trigsize_10um.png}\par 
    \subfloat[legend]{\label{c}\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{abb/plots/gauss_trigsize_5um.png}
    \caption{my fig}
\end{figure}
```

i am using the `\usepackage{subfig,graphicx,showframe}` package and I deleted the other `\usepackage{subfigure}`. but still I am getting the error **file ended while scanning use of \sf@@@subfloat**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the closing `}` of each `\subfloat{}`. You have `\subfloat[..]{\includegraphics{...}`, but it should be `\subfloat[..]{\includegraphics{...}}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig,graphicx,showframe,float}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
    \subfloat[legend]{\label{a}\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{abb/plots/gauss_trigsize_20um.png}}\hfill
    \subfloat[legend]{\label{b}\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{abb/plots/gauss_trigsize_10um.png}}\par 
    \subfloat[legend]{\label{c}\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{abb/plots/gauss_trigsize_5um.png}}
    \caption{my fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```